# How do I open a wsl workspace in VS Code for a different distro?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote

I have both Ubuntu and Debian installed for WSL. When I open a WSL workspace using [VS Code remote development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview), it always opens Ubuntu. How can I open a workspace under the Debian install using WSL in VS Code?

Comment: you can check out this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75929012/vscode-not-opening-in-wsl-from-wsl-terminal/76514219#76514219](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75929012/vscode-not-opening-in-wsl-from-wsl-terminal/76514219#76514219)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The VS Code [Remote - WSL extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl) always uses the default WSL distro. You can change the default distro using the [`wsl` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config) (`wslconfig` on earlier windows versions):

```
# List the available distributions
wsl --list
```

[image: Listing distributions with the wsl --list command]

```
# Set the default version to debian
wsl --setdefault debian
```

[image: Switch the default distro with the wsl --setDefault command]

After changing the default for WSL, make sure to restart VS Code

Answer (score 4):

Click the "remote button" in the bottom left

[image: remote button screenshot]

Choose `New Window using Distro...`

[image: new windows using distro screenshot]

Pick your distro!

[image: pick distro screenshot]