# VSCode not opening in WSL from WSL terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote

When I type `code .` inside Windows Terminal in my Ubuntu shell it opens VSCode normally but it is not connected to WSL. It automatically detects that my workspace is in WSL so it displays a notification to *Reopen folder in WSL*.

It used to work as described in the documentation: typing `code .` from within WSL, opened a VSCode instance that was connected to WSL directly.

Is there a setting I can use to tell VSCode to use WSL when it is open from a WSL terminal ?

I tried typing `code .` from within VSCode, inside a workspace that was open in WSL. It correctly opened a new window connected to WSL.

I also tried typing the command inside Powershell with

```
wsl
code .
```

but it didn't work either. It opened a new window not connected to any remote.

I tried using the `--remote` option from a WSL terminal but nothing happened.

Comment: Did you install WSL extension? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl

Answer (score 1):

Download this extension from

[https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdgkP.png)

[image]

Whenever you open a project that belongs/inside your Ubuntu Wsl Vscode will prompt you and advise you to reopen the project in Wsl.

if that method didn't workout here is what you need to do. goto remote explorer in your Vscode and change

[image]

Change the target to WSL target, and you will see the list of projects you have currently in your Wsl, just double-click on anyone, and vs code will lunch it for you